# Copy file to solution

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a file in a class library.

I need to reference it from the class library via a utils lib. If I do this `"~/myfile.xsd`", the file isn't found as it's looking for a reference in the solution root.

As far as I can see I have 2 options:

1. Copy it to the solution root
2. Change the path to reference the current assembly

At the moment, I've tried all permutations of Build Action to try and get the file to copy - the only things that has worked is physically copying the file ocross to the root.

However, the file doesn't need to be in the solution root so I guess referencing it in the currently assembly would be the best choice anyway, but how can I do this?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit?  You need the xsd at runtime, but you only have it in your solution at the root? A screen shot, or representation of your project structure, plus some examples of how you are using it may help.

Comment: I have a class library that utilises an xml file, and I also want to use an xsd (entirely within the class library). The xml file on the otherhand is unique within the solution so I place this in the root. A function inside the class library deserialises the xml, using the xsd, so it doesn't need to reside outside the class.

Comment: In that case I'd Embed it as a resource and pull it from a MemoryStream using ResourceManager.GetManifestResourceStream and then load it into your XML serializer.  No copying necessary.

Comment: So I hace to embed the resource (XSD) even though I'm accessing it from the same namespace in the same project?

Comment: XSD isn't anything special with regard to namespaces or assemblies and .NET doesn't know anything directly about them, so if you are going to deploy the file so that '~' works, you will need to manually ensure that the file is there.  If it's an entirely internal thing, it is easier to embed the file than worry about the semantics of copying the file to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options.  Convert the file in to a resource as Steve Mitcham commented, or select the file in solution explorer, in the property grid change `BuildAction` to None, and `Copy to output directory` to `Copy if newer` or `Copy always`.  The 2nd option will cause Visual Studio to place the file in the bin directory along with your exe when it is compiled.